# Can .bash_profile be auto sourced after change?

Tags: bash, shell, profile

I'm always wondering if there's a way to do this. I don't want to type `source` after changing my `.bash_profile` all the time.

Comment: Log back in (if typing `source .bash_profile` is too much trouble)...

Comment: `. ~/.bash_profile` saves you a pair of keystrokes...

Comment: @jasonwryan I use alias now so I just want to know if auto source is possible...

Comment: @laike9m I doubt it. Bash doesn't monitor the configuration files. You'll have to use an alias or function of some form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to make it happen automatically with a little work using [`PROMPT_COMMAND`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-PROMPT_005fCOMMAND) and [`-nt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions-1) with a marker file. If you put this into your `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
touch /tmp/bash_profile-$$
resource_profile() {
    [ ~/.bash_profile -nt /tmp/bash_profile-$$ ] && source ~/.bash_profile
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=resource_profile
```

then an empty marker file will be created in `/tmp` when the shell starts, named with the [PID](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_0024_0024) of the shell to identify it.

Before displaying the prompt every time the shell will run the `resource_profile` function, which will check whether `~/.bash_profile` has changed (`-nt`) since the last time it was sourced and updated the marker file, and will automatically `source ~/.bash_profile` if it has changed. When the file is sourced it will update the marker file again for the next time.

This isn't foolproof - depending on the filesystem, changes made shortly after the file is sourced may not be detected. The file will only be checked after you run a command or press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which is as close to immediate as it's possible to get, but not completely instantaneous.

Depending on the profile of your system you may prefer to put the marker file elsewhere where nobody else can access the directory. It's also possible to build something similar out of [`stat(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) if you have it, avoiding the marker file entirely.